# Identify dropdown and its list items like google search in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a dropdown , which works same as our google search textbox, once the user types input, it will provide suggestions but if there is no match it will accept users inout. I have to identify this dropdown, its elements and accept user input if there is no suitable match in selenium webdriver java. It will need a for loop to match with the options fetched. But how do I implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to find the selector for your suggestion box, then click on it.

So for example, Google uses this selector `#sbtc > div.gstl_0.sbdd_a > div:nth-child(2) > div.sbdd_b > div > ul > li:nth-child(1)` as one of its suggestion boxes. You need to identify this element with `Selenium` and click:

```
String yourSelector = "#sbtc > div.gstl_0.sbdd_a > div:nth-child(2) > div.sbdd_b > div > ul > li:nth-child(1)";
driver.findElement(By.css(yourSelector)).click();
```

And if `findElement` does not return you anything, you can safely assume there is no match and then use user input instead